# How to change ports defined in server.xml when I want to load multi tomcat instance

Tags: tomcat

Anybody list up every ports in server.xml of Tomcat?
For loading multi tomcat instances in one computer, what kinds of port do I have to change and prevent to be duplicated?

Like followings, there are many port settings.

```
<Server port="28005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">


<Connector port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8190" 
               useBodyEncodingForURI="

<Connector port="28009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Refer this http://crunchify.com/how-to-run-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-one-server/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the protocol you want to use.

For exemple for multiple HTTP instances:

```
<!-- HTTP Connector -->
<Connector port="NumberToChange" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"/>
```